# QTableWidget clone

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I know that QTableWidget has no copy constructor since (correct me if I'm wrong) it's based on view/model paradigm.

But it could happen that you need a copy of the `QTableWidget`, when, for example, you have to do some kind of operations in a function and you don't want to affect the view on the widget. For example:

- You may want to export the table to a png file:

  ```
  void exportMyTable(const QTableWidget& table){
      ...
      table.grab().save(fileExportFilePath);
  }
  ```

  ...but `grab` method is not const (I can't understand why...), so you need to create a local copy before.
- You may want to copy it to clipboard or export to csv, so you need to remove all the cell spans before export it and having a temporary `QTableWidget` copy could help.
- ...etc...

BTW, a workaround could be to copy all the content cell by cell:

```
void exportMyTable(const QTableWidget& table){
    QTableWidget copyTable;
    copyTable.setRowCount(table.rowCount());
    copyTable.setColumnCount(table.columnCount());
    for (int c = 0; c < table.columnCount(); ++c)   
        for (int r = 0; r < table.rowCount(); ++r)
            copyTable.setSpan(r, c, table.rowSpan(r, c), table.columnSpan(r, c));
    ...
}
```

but the above code crashes in case of cell span, so I need to copy all the spans, then all the headers, etc...

So, back to original question, is there a way to clone a `QTableWidget` in a easiest way? Both model and view in a new object.

Comment: Do you really need a deep copy? What is your original task? I recommend to [read this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: I have listed in my question some cases when a deep copy could help.

Comment: I think `QWidget::grab()` is not a const function because it calls `QWidget::paint()` to render the widget on an image.

Comment: Not ideal but I think a `const_cast` is a much better work around than a deep copy of your widget to use [`QWidget::grab`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab).